# Compass: Importing files from another project directory

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have two projects. One is for the public facing side of our site and the other is for the admin side. I have a page that is the same on both pages.

My directory structure is like so:

```
/public
  config.rb
  /images
    /upgrade
      /sprites
  /sass
    /upgrade
        index.scss
  /stylesheets

/cms
  config.rb
  /sass
    /upgrade
        index.scss
  /stylesheets
```

`public/sass/upgrade/index.scss` is where all of the styles live. `cms/sass/upgrade/index.scss` imports those styles, like so:

```
@import '../../../public/sass/upgrade'
```

These works fine in that I can generate css into `cms/stylesheets/upgrade/index.css`. It is with the sprite generation that I'm running into a problem. Inside of `public/sass/upgrade/index.scss`, the import for the sprite pngs looks like this

```
@import 'upgrade/sprites/*.png';
```

Using LiveReload, I get the follow error:

```
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
No files were found in the load path matching "setup/packages/*.png". Your current load paths are: ./images
```

That makes sense because when I compile my `cms/sass/upgrade/index.scss`, its looking for images in `cms/images/upgrade/sprites` where there are none.

I'm curious to see if anyone has ever run into this issue and has any solutions how to share assets across projects. I thought that setting `relative_assets = true` would help but it hasn't. Maybe I'm using it wrong. I don't know.

Comment: You *can* make `images_dir` point to wherever you want, including outside of the project directory.

Comment: I need images_dir to point to their respective project image directories. It's just this one case where I need to load images from both.

Comment: Does making a symbolic link for the images work?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Please review my answer and accept it if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that cimmanon's suggestion to create a symbolic link should work. Are you sure you're doing it correctly? To be on the safe side, use an absolute path.

Your project structure is kinda funny, i failed to fully comprehend it, so i can't give you exact symlink placement and target. If you want us to provide you exact paths, please update your question with:

1. where you place the symlink, where it points to, what errors you have when you attempt to compile;
2. more detailed project structure (full contents of files involved would be of help).

**UPD:** make sure your Apache configuration has [FollowSymLinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Options) enabled and PHP configuration has all the projects directories in the [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

If you give it up, you can use a nasty hack that i have just invented. :D

The idea is to create a custom SASS function that returns different result depending on from what project it is called. This will let importing different paths from `public/sass/upgrade/index.scss` depending on which project you're compiling.

In `public/config.rb`, add:

```
# Assign a name to the project and pass it into SASS
$project_name = "public"
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def project_name
    Sass::Script::String.new($project_name)
  end
end
```

The addition to `cms/config.rb` is quite similar. The only difference is $project_name's value:

```
# Assign a name to the project and pass it into SASS
$project_name = "cms"
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def project_name
    Sass::Script::String.new($project_name)
  end
end
```

After that, modify the import line in `public/sass/upgrade/index.scss`:

```
@if project-name() == public {
  @import 'upgrade/sprites/*.png';
} @else if project-name() == cms {
  @import '../../../public/upgrade/sprites/*.png';
}
```

The import paths in my example are crooked, please adjust them to match your environment.

**UPD2:** the `@import` directives are not allowed inside control directives like `@if`. So  instead you can use:

```
@if project-name() == public {
  $path: 'upgrade/sprites/*.png';
} @else if project-name() == cms {
  $path: '../../../public/upgrade/sprites/*.png';
}
@import #{$path};
```