# sass/scss @import when relative path is symlink

Tags: symfony, import, sass, relative-path, symlink

We have trouble with `@import` of scss files from another bundle in symfony2.

- The source code (hg repo) lives in `/files/...` in machine A.
- In devel, apache serves from `/var/www/...` in machine A, **linking** to `/files/...` in machine A.
- In production, apache serves from `/var/www/...` in machine B, with **copies** of the source files inside.

Let's focus on a single `Layout.scss` file that contains coloring and sizing definitions. These are my paths:

```
# Source code (machine A)
xavi@bromo$ cd /files/custom_www/guparty/workspace/guparty/Applications/Common/bundles/LayoutBundle/Resources/public/Sass
xavi@bromo$ ls -l Layout.scss
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xavi xavi 7528 2013-03-28 12:18 Layout.scss

# Devel (machine A)
xavi@bromo$ cd /var/www/guparty/workspace/www/frontend/src/gUparty/
xavi@bromo$ ls -l Common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xavi xavi 71 2013-03-28 12:26 Common -> /files/custom_www/guparty/workspace/guparty/Applications/Common/bundles

# Production (machine B)
ubuntu@ProductionLarge1$ cd /var/www/www.guparty.com/src/gUparty/
ubuntu@ProductionLarge1$ ls -ld Common/
drwxr-xr-x 21 www-data www-data 4096 2013-03-28 07:35 Common/
```

Now let's consider the file `Test.scss` that will include the previous file:

```
# Seen from the source code point of view:
/files/custom_www/guparty/workspace/guparty/Applications/FrontEnd/bundles/TestingBundle/Resources/public/Sass/Test.scss

# Seen from the devel apache point of view (links to the one above):
/var/www/guparty/workspace/www/frontend/src/gUparty/FrontEnd/TestingBundle/Resources/public/Sass/Test.scss

# Seen from the production apache point of view:
/var/www/www.guparty.com/src/gUparty/FrontEnd/TestingBundle/Resources/public/Sass/Test.scss
```

The `Test.scss` file begins with an `@import` directive like this one:

```
@import "../../../../../../../src/gUparty/Common/LayoutBundle/Resources/public/Sass/Layout.scss";
```

**The trouble**

Seen from the production machine, which contains COPIES of the files, it works like a charm.

Nevertheless, when running from the devel machine, I expected it to work, as the **relative** path is the same. Instead, the operating system **does not show** the linked files to the apache/php, and it appears that the assetic "needs to know" the real path.

In devel, the import fails, and if I change the `@import` into this, it works fine:

```
@import "../../../../../../../Applications/Common/bundles/LayoutBundle/Resources/public/Sass/Layout.scss";
```

**Solutions that I see, but don't know how to implement**

a) Maybe I could configure something so the PHP sees the "relative paths without demapping the symlinks".

b) Maybe I can pass a "variable" from the parameters.ini or similar into the .scss file so I can "discover" if I'm in "linked mode" or "copied mode" and make the `@import` to use one path or the other.

Any way to implement a or b?
Any preference between those two strategies?
Any alternative strategy?

Thanks!
Xavi.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are possible.

> a) Maybe I could configure something so the PHP sees the "relative paths without demapping the symlinks".

Make sure your Apache configuration has FollowSymLinks enabled and PHP configuration has all the projects directories in the include_path.

> b) Maybe I can pass a "variable" from the parameters.ini or similar into the .scss file so I can "discover" if I'm in "linked mode" or "copied mode" and make the @import to use one path or the other.

Create a custom SASS function that returns different result depending on from what project it is called. This will let importing different paths from public/sass/upgrade/index.scss depending on which project you're compiling.

See [Compass: Importing files from another project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656555/compass-importing-files-from-another-project-directory/15683333#15683333) for details on both.

Comment: About "a)" `FollowSymLinks` is not the problem. Actually our apache has already `FollowSymLinks` set. The problem is that when following, it "demaps" into the "real" path which mangles the "relativeness" seen from inside. Note that the caller and the called reside one in `Common` and one in `FrontEnd`. In absolute paths, bundles are under `Common/bundles/LayoutBundle` but seen from the linked path it is `Common/LayoutBundle` (without `bundles`). I would need that `FollowSymLinks` does not "demap" the route and leaves it "as is" seen from inside the linked directory.

Comment: About "b)" I cannot imagine where should I set the variable in a Symfony2 project so it arrives inside the `scss` to be evaluated.

Comment: For b) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690372/how-do-i-load-extensions-to-the-sassscriptfunctions-module Don't forget to upvote and select the answer. ;)